# Config Transformations - How can I locate self node?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, app-config

I have transform files made on `App.config` and I want to remove one attribute.

**App.config**

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings file="App.private.config">
        <add key="RestorePoint" value="1298640.0" />
        <add key="ReleaseType" value="Test" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

**App.release.config**

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings file="" xdt:Transform="Remove" xdt:Locator="Match(.)>
        <add key="ReleaseType" value="" xdt:Transform="Remove" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

All I want achieve is to remove `file` attribute from `appSettings` node and completely remove `ReleaseType` from settings. When I don't have any problems with removing `ReleaseType`, I cannot erase `file` attribute. Do you have any ideas how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found solution:

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <appSettings file="" xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(file)" xdt:Locator="XPath(.)">
        <add key="ReleaseType" value="" xdt:Transform="Remove" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I shoudl have used `xdt:Locator="XPath(.)"` and `xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(file)"` instead of setting empty value.